# for every $p\in f^{-1}(\{a\})$ there is an open neighbourhood $W\subset U$ such that $f^{-1}(\{a\})\cap W$ is the graph of a $C^1$-function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $Df(p)\not= 0$ for all $p\in f^{-1}(\{a\})$. I want to know how to prove: for every $p\in f^{-1}(\{a\})$ there is an open neighbourhood $W\subset U$ such that $f^{-1}(\{a\})\cap W$ is the graph of a $C^1$-function. What is if $f(p)=\|p\|^2$ and $a>0$?

I tried to start with the implicit function Theorem, but I dont know how to continue.

Consider the continuously differentiable function $F:U\to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto f(x)-a$. It is $F(p)=0$ for all $p\in f^{-1}(\{a\})$ and $DF(p)=Df(p)\not=0$. Fix $i\in\{,..,n\}$, i=n. The Theorem gives us open neighbourhoods $U$ of $(p_1,..,p_{n-1})$ and $V$ of $p_i$ and a continuously differentiable function $h:U\to V$  such that $h(p_1,..p_{n-1})=p_n$. But I don't know how to continoue.

I think, $f^{-1}(\{a\})\cap W$ could be the graph of the $C^1$-function h, with $W=U\times V$, but I'm not sure. And I have no idea how to do the second part of the question.

Comment: Something is wrong with your question. $f^{-1}(\{a\}) \cap W$ is a subset of $U$. How can a subset of the domain be the graph of a function? Do you mean $f$ restricted to $W$ is still $C^1$? Or are you trying to show $f$ is invertible and has $C^1$ inverse?

Comment: I find it strange too, but this is the original-question (only translated in english). I think, the $C^1$ function is the function h and maybe $W=U\times V$.